# how to generate mst file as difference of 2 msi files

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to generate an mst file after making changes to an msi file. My approach is like this.

1. Take a copy of the original .msi file.
2. Make all the modifications in the msi file copy.

Now i have 2 msi files original.msi and modified.msi . Is  there any way i can generate the .mst file by taking a difference of modified.msi-original.msi. I found this command line tool of installshield MsiDiff.exe to generate the difference in a log file.Is there a way to generate the mst file based on the difference .

```
"C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2014\System\MsiDiff.exe" "C:\InstallShield 2014 Projects\MyProject1.msi" "C:\InstallShield 2014 Projects\MyProject2.msi" /out "C:\Log File.xml"
```

I am looking for a command line tool which takes 'orig.msi' and 'modified.msi' as inputs and can generate the difference as an mst file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the windows sdk u get this vbs :

```
' Windows Installer utility to generate a transform from two databases
' For use with Windows Scripting Host, CScript.exe or WScript.exe
' Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
' Demonstrates use of Database.GenerateTransform and MsiDatabaseGenerateTransform
'
Option Explicit

Const msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly     = 0
Const msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact     = 1
Const msiOpenDatabaseModeCreate       = 3

If Wscript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Windows Installer database tranform generation utility" &_
        vbNewLine & " 1st argument is the path to the original installer database" &_
        vbNewLine & " 2nd argument is the path to the updated installer database" &_
        vbNewLine & " 3rd argument is the path to the transform file to generate" &_
        vbNewLine & " If the 3rd argument is omitted, the databases are only compared" &_
        vbNewLine &_
        vbNewLine & "Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved."
    Wscript.Quit 1
End If

' Connect to Windows Installer object
On Error Resume Next
Dim installer : Set installer = Nothing
Set installer = Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer") : CheckError

' Open databases and generate transform
Dim database1 : Set database1 = installer.OpenDatabase(Wscript.Arguments(0), msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly) : CheckError
Dim database2 : Set database2 = installer.OpenDatabase(Wscript.Arguments(1), msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly) : CheckError
Dim transform:transform = ""  'Simply compare if no output transform file supplied
If Wscript.Arguments.Count >= 3 Then transform = Wscript.Arguments(2)
    Dim different:different = Database2.GenerateTransform(Database1, transform) : CheckError
If Not different Then Wscript.Echo "Databases are identical" Else If transform = Empty Then Wscript.Echo "Databases are different"

Sub CheckError
    Dim message, errRec
    If Err = 0 Then Exit Sub
    message = Err.Source & " " & Hex(Err) & ": " & Err.Description
    If Not installer Is Nothing Then
        Set errRec = installer.LastErrorRecord
        If Not errRec Is Nothing Then message = message & vbNewLine & errRec.FormatText
    End If
    Wscript.Echo message
    Wscript.Quit 2
End Sub
```

the script take 3 arguments : original db, update db and finally the 3rd is the mst fullpath

Comment: is the script name wigenxfm.vbs

Comment: yes, its this one : "WiGenXfm.vbs - generates a transform from two databases, or compares them"

Comment: I having one issue using this vbs. I am able to get a difference.But all changes in summary info in the udated msi not getting reflected in the mst generated.

Comment: same issue here WiGenXfm.vbs applies all other changes but in summary information whatever change i am doing is not getting reflected in mst.. is there any other option for this? @Meliart